# Syntax error When I try to run backend code

Tags: python, python-3.x, model-view-controller, syntax, python-class

When I try to run the server I get syntax error.  But there isn`t any incorrect using of syntax. Please help to correct this issue! [Issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWeB7.png%60)

```
from blacksheep.server.application import Application
from blacksheep.server.controllers import Controller, get, post
from blacksheep.cookies import Cookie
from blacksheep.messages import Response
from easy_cryptography.hash.hash_funct import compare_hash
from app.configuration import AUTHORIZED
from models import Doctors
from pony.orm import *

class Home(Controller):
    
    @get("/")
    def index(self):
        return self.view()

class Patients(Controller):

    @post("/patients")
    def patients(self, login: str, password: str):
        if Doctors.exists(login) and (compare_hash(password, Doctors.get_for_update(login = login).password)):
            patients = Patients.select()
            response = self.view(patients=patients)
            response.set_cookie(Cookie(AUTHORIZED,True))
            return response
        else:
            return "{'message':'Неверный логин или пароль'}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `async` keyword before `def index(self):`

Another bug I can see is that you are not binding the parameters to your `patients` method correctly from the `@post` decorator.